# Calculate percentage in conditional formatting expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I got a condition

```
**If charges of any week is zero then that cell has to be highlighted in red

o If  charges of any week is 80% to 90% of total average then cell has to be highlighted in
lime

o If  charges of any week is less than 79% of total average then it cell has to be highlighted
in light orange**
```

i tried  the following condition:

```
IIF((SUM(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value)<>0),"Red","White",iif(sum(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value>=80% and sum(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value<=90% ,Fields!ChargeAmount.Value,"")
```

Can anyone can help me with this .

Comment: It seems that you have grouped the report by week and are calculating the weekly amount using `Sum(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value)`. But how are you calculating the overall average of these weekly sums? Is this part of the question? Have you grouped your report by weeks? Please let us know what is contained in the dataset (just a date or already a week number) and also how you have set up the grouping in the report.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Yes it is grouped ,by weeks

Comment: So you are calculating the weekly sum in the header or the footer of that group and try to format the cell, right?. But how are you calculating the overall average of these weekly sums? Is this part of the question? Do you calculate the "week ID" (if so, how?) or is it already contained in your dataset? What are the names of the controls with the weekly sum and the total average?

Comment: If sum of charges of any week is 80% to 90% of total average then cell has to be highlighted in
"lime".I am calculating total average of avg(case when transactiontype IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') then ChargeAmount end) AS [Weekly Average].I am not getting output for this :=Switch(SUM(Fields!Charges_Billed.Value)=0,"Red",
    (SUM(Fields!Charges_Billed.Value) >= 0.8) 
 and
  (SUM(Fields!Charges_Billed.Value) <= 0.9), "Lime",
SUM(Fields!Charges_Billed.Value)<=0.79,"Orange")

Comment: Your `[Weekly Average]` seems to be just the the average charge amount per week. This will be the sum devided by the number of charge amounts, and it makes no sense to compare that value to the sum. I thought that you wanted a *Total Average*?

Comment: the weekly average is the total average

Comment: Acccording to your formula, it is an average on (all) charge amouns but not on weekly sums, that's what I was thinking and that's why I was asking. Have a look at the formula I provided in my answer. The "Total Average" has to be calculated as the total sum divided by the number of weeks.

Comment: Ok i will try it  and get back to you

Comment: i am getting error for this statement: Variables!FractionOfTotalAverage.Value < 0.5, "Red",

Comment: I am not seeing the error you get. Where and how did you define the variable? Where are you using the variable (group footer?)?

Comment: below the matrix report under design:Under Row Group->FirstOFWeek->Group Properties->Variables Tab->Add->Name:FractionOfTotalAverage-> Value- Add Expression ok,Then go to the FirstOf week ->Properties->BackgroundColor->Expression->=Switch(
  Variables!FractionOfTotalAverage.Value < 0.5, "Red")

Comment: Sounds great, so make sure that the field names in the expression for the variable are correct (`Fields!Charges_Billed.Value` and `Fields!FirstOFWeek.Value`) and also that the name of the dataset in the formula ("WeeklyCharges" in my example) is the name of your dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed that your dataset is named "WeeklyCharges" and the field you use to group by week is named "FirstOfWeek", try the following:

In the properties of the group (FirstOfWeek), define a variable `FractionOfTotalAverage` using the expression

```
=Sum(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value)
  / (Sum(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value, "WeeklyCharges")
    / CountDistinct(Fields!FirstOfWeek.Value, "WeeklyCharges"))
```

For the *BackgroundColor* property of your weekly charges TextBox, use an expression like this:

```
=Switch(
  Variables!FractionOfTotalAverage.Value < 0.5, "Red",
  Variables!FractionOfTotalAverage.Value < 0.8, "Yellow",
  Variables!FractionOfTotalAverage.Value < 0.9, "Lime")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
IIF((SUM(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value) = 0), "Red",
    IIF(SUM(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value) >= 80 and SUM(Fields!ChargeAmount.Value) <= 90, "Lime", "Orange")))
```

Comment: but i need to calculate 80% to 90%  ,is it going to work like 80 only and not 80%

Comment: @RoverRoll so do you have any other field where is stored total average to calculate the percentage?